# WP7 listbox binds to second observable collection autoselection error

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, data-binding, listbox

I have a list box which is bound to a Service. It loads fine and allows me to select an item and moves through to second page.

The Second page loads a new observable collection from the same service and uses the selected Item from previous page to load a new listbox with a data filter.

This second listbox allows for a further selection to load a details page based on this selection. The error I have is that the second listbox loads and automatically selects the first item in the list. Upon pushing the back button it loads the second listbox with no selection made.

Can someone please tell me how to stop the automatic selection in my second listbox? Code details below.

First Listbox code including sender

```
void ServiceReference1Client_GetMensleaderListCompleted(object sender, GetMensLeaderListCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null) { MensHeading.Text = "Connect to Data"; return; }

        ObservableCollection<Mens_Leaders> mensLeaders = e.Result;

        this.mensRankings.ItemsSource = mensLeaders;

    }

    private void mensRankings_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (mensRankings.SelectedItem != null)
        {
            Mens_Leaders SelectedPlayer = mensRankings.SelectedItem as Mens_Leaders;
            _SelectedMensPlayer = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/PlayerProfile.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            FrameworkElement root2 = Application.Current.RootVisual as FrameworkElement;
            root2.DataContext = _SelectedMensPlayer;
        }
    }
```

Page where second list loads

```
private void LoadPlayerList()
    {
        Service1Client ServiceReference1Client = new Service1Client();

        ServiceReference1Client.GetTournamentListCompleted += new EventHandler<GetTournamentListCompletedEventArgs>(ServiceReference1Client_GetTournamentListCompleted);
        ServiceReference1Client.GetTournamentListAsync();

        FrameworkElement root2 = Application.Current.RootVisual as FrameworkElement;
        var currentPlayer = root2.DataContext as ATP_Tennis_App.TennisService.Mens_Leaders;
        _SelectedPlayer = currentPlayer;
        _selectedPlayerTournamentsWon = currentPlayer.Name;

    }
void ServiceReference1Client_GetTournamentListCompleted(object sender, GetTournamentListCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Error != null) { return; }

        ObservableCollection<Tournaments> tournamentList = e.Result;

        viewSource = new CollectionViewSource();
        viewSource.Filter += TournamentWin_Filter;
        viewSource.Source = tournamentList;
        this.listBox1.ItemsSource = viewSource.View;
    }

    void TournamentWin_Filter(object sender, FilterEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item != null)
            e.Accepted = ((Tournaments)e.Item).Prev_Male_Winner.Contains(_selectedPlayerTournamentsWon);
    }

    private void listBox1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (listBox1.SelectedItem != null)
        {

            Tournaments selectedTournament1 = listBox1.SelectedItem as Tournaments;

            _SelectedItemTournament = (sender as ListBox).SelectedItem;
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Pages/TournamentDetailsPanorama.xaml", UriKind.Relative));
            FrameworkElement root3 = Application.Current.RootVisual as FrameworkElement;
            root3.DataContext = _SelectedItemTournament;

        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On the listbox, set the IsSynchroziedWithCurrentItem to False. This fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a dirty solution, but you can set listBox1.SelectedIndex = -1